# Creating HTML objects from javascript object then move them on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a homework problem where 4 characters appear in a row, one is clicked and stays, the others move to a new row. Once in that row another is clicked again to be the opponent and that one moves to a new row for the fight.

I was going to build the character cards using jquery and move them with that as well. I tried using a for loop but it iterates each character in the object in each character column instead of doing one each. The end result is all 4 of the character names appear in the first column, then just the last 3, then just the last 2, and then the last one. I am trying to iterate through so the first column contains the name, picture, and hitpoints of the first character and repeat for each character.

As far as moving the character cards around, I was going to try to detach and prepend to the target row but my click function is returning an undefined instead of the name of the character selected.

I tried an alternate method but that is not working either. Both are included in the code

Main JS File

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    /* 
    - make object for each playable character
    - for each character make a variable for their hitpoints
    */
    var characters = [
        {
            name:  "Rey",
            hitPoints: 150,
            counterattack: 20,
            picture: "../images/rey-red-saber.jpg"
        },
        {
            name: "Boba Fett",
            hitPoints: 100,
            counterattack: 50,
            picture: "../images/Boba2.jpeg"
        },
        {
            name: "Grievous",
            hitPoints: 200,
            counterattack: 10,
            picture: "../images/Grievous.jpg"
        },
        {
            name: "Phasma",
            hitPoints: 180,
            counterattack: 15,
            picture: "../images/Phasma.jpg"
        }
    ]
    
    for(var i = 0; i< characters.length; i++){
        $(".charRow").append("<div class='col-md-2 charCol'></div>");
        $(".charCol").append("<div class='card text-center charCard'></div>");
        $(".charCard").append("<div class='card-header'>" + characters[i].name + "</div>");
        // $(".card-header").html("<img class='card-img-top charImg' src=" + characters)

    }

        });
```

Alternate JS file

```js
    ///var chosen;
var myChar = "";

var characters = {
    rey: {
        name:  "Rey",
        hitPoints: 150,
        counterattack: 20
    },
    boba: {
        name: "Boba Fett",
        hitPoints: 100,
        counterattack: 50
    },
    grievous: {
        name: "Grievous",
        hitPoints: 200,
        counterattack: 10
    },
    phasma: {
        name: "Phasma",
        hitPoints: 180,
        counterattack: 15
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
/* 
- make object for each playable character
- for each character make a variable for their hitpoints
*/

$(".charCol").click(function(){
    if(myChar == "") {
        myChar = $(this);
        console.log(myChar);
        chosen = $(myChar).attr("value");
        console.log(chosen)
    };
    // console.log(chosen)
    if(chosen == "rey"){
        
    }
});

});
```

HTML PAGE

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>The Force Is Strong Here</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="assets/javascript/game.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Faster+One|Geostar+Fill&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body class="background">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 titleContainer">
                <div id="title">Star Wars RPG</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row charRow">
           
        </div>
        <div class="row titleRow">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2 class="charTitle">Your Character</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row enemyRow">

        </div>
        <div class="row titleRow">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2 class="charTitle">Enemies Available To Attack</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row titleRow">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2 class="charTitle">Fight Section</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row titleRow">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2 class="charTitle">Defender</h2>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 charCol">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Attack</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please ask a single, specific question and what you've tried, rather than explain the entire program and ask for help with all of it.

Comment: I have a javascript object that I want to iterate through to make a bootstrap card with a header for the name, a picture for the body, and hit points for the footer. When I try to iterate through it currently it puts all the names in each card instead of following the format I laid out above. How do I make it so I can create a bootstrap column with a single card with a header, single picture for a card body, and a single card footer then move on to the next character and do the same thing and continue for each character that way.

Comment: This is not a specific question. It’s a question about to create a solution. Please ask a single specific question along with what you’ve tried.

Comment: The specific question is how to iterate through the javascript object to create the elements in HTML using jQuery. I've laid out what I tried in the code in 2 instances. Specifically referencing the for loop in the Main JS file labeled above. I tried it using .append, .html, and with .appends in a single line of code but they have all either not worked at all or added mutliple characters in the same column instead of a column for each. I'm not sure what else is missing?